# Cant resize UILabel to fit its content

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I have UILabel with text in it, I want that text to be truncated to two lines, and after I click it, I want UILabel to expand enough, so that it will fit entire text.

This works, when the XIB is loaded, it will resize the UILabel:
'''

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        postLabel.numberOfLines = 0
}
```

'''

But when I call this on button click, nothing happens. That button click works, I have a print statement there, which gets executed, its just that numberOfLines doesnt change anything. I thought this might have something to do with rendering UI elements, so perhaps I need to redraw the UI? Since in awakeFromNib it works, but doesnt work afterwards.

I also tried

```
postLabel.sizeToFit()
```

but that simply doesnt do anything, no matter whether it is in awakeFromNib function or any button IBAction

Comment: The missing part of your question is constraints. (Unless you are using frames - but even then you'll need to make sure you resize the height.) Could you add those details?

Comment: I have constraints to superview on top, trailing, leading to zero. I have one constraint for height which I have as outlet connected to my controller.